# Is there anyway to have React breadcrumbs in VSCode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, breadcrumbs

VSCode has breadcrumbs which is very useful to navigate between tags in a long HTML file. But in a `jsx` file the breadcrumbs stop when it reaches the `return` statement, effectively making this feature non-existent in any rendering part of React.

Is there a setting, an extension or anything that solves this problem? I feel like this should've been a thing by now, with React being around for quite some time.

[image: My cursor is on Container in the pic]

I did find one VSCode extension called [React Outline](https://github.com/ShubhamVerma1811/vscode-react-outline), but the breadcrumbs doesn't update when I move my cursor around. It doesn't seem to have lots of features either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[React Breadcrumbs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nemothecollector.jsx-breadcrumbs&ssr=false#overview) VsCode extension already does it nicely. It helps see the React component trees and jump to these components with either outline tab or `Cmd+shift+.` command.